# Dynamically adapt height of scrollable content (Ion Page, React)

Tags: css, reactjs, ionic-framework, mobile, scroll

Say you have some  text in your ionic react page that is quite large and so you want it to scroll instead of filling your entire page, then the following styling will help a lot:

```js
<div  style={{ overflow: 'auto', flex: '1 1 auto', height: '200px'}}>
Some Text
</>
```

But let's assume, I have a page with some content and a footer, e.g. like this:

```js
<IonPage>
      <IonContent>
        <h2>Search Detail Page</h2>
        <IonItem>
          Some Search Result Details
        </IonItem>

        <h1> Description</h1>
        <div  style={{ overflow: 'auto', flex: '1 1 auto'}}>
          <p>This is the content that matters to me. I want this to scroll when this description gets so long, that the footer would start covering it</p>
          <p>Now let's put a whole lot of text in this paragraph so we can demonstrate what happens if we have a long text. Repeat after me: Now let's put a lot of text in this paragraph so we can demonstrate what happens if we have a long text. Repeat after me: Now let's put a lot of text in this paragraph so we can demonstrate what happens if we have a long text. Repeat after me: Now let's put a lot of text in this paragraph so we can demonstrate what happens if we have a long text. Repeat after me: Now let's put a lot of text in this paragraph so we can demonstrate what happens if we have a long text. Repeat after me: Now let's put a lot of text in this paragraph so we can demonstrate what happens if we have a long text. Repeat after me: Now let's put a lot of text in this paragraph so we can demonstrate what happens if we have a long text. Repeat after me: Now let's put a lot of text in this paragraph so we can demonstrate what happens if we have a long text. Repeat after me: Now let's put a lot of text in this paragraph so we can demonstrate what happens if we have a long text. Repeat after me: Now let's put a lot of text in this paragraph so we can demonstrate what happens if we have a long text. Repeat after me: </p>
        </div>
      </IonContent>

      <IonFooter>
        <IonToolbar>
          Some shiny footer content
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonFooter>
    </IonPage>
```

On phones, it will look like this:

[image]

Note that the description content is not scrollable because the height of the dev is not limited. The problem is, that we need to define a "max-height", which we can't, do because the page size will vary on different devices, plus it depends on the footer height.

Any suggestions? It seems like such a common problem and yet, I can't find an answer.

I tried this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const h2Height = document.querySelector('h2').clientHeight;
      const itemHeight = document.querySelector('ion-item').clientHeight;

      console.log('Header Height:', h2Height); // sadly, this is 0 at init time. But then works on reload
      console.log('Item Height:', itemHeight);


      if (descriptionRef.current) {
        descriptionRef.current.style.height = `calc(100% - ${h2Height + itemHeight}px - 2em)`;
      }
    }, 100); // we need this 100ms timeout, since otherwise the heights are not available and equals 0 at load time
  }, []);

//...
<h1> Description</h1>
<div ref={descriptionRef}>Some very long detailed description</div>
```

This only works when I reload the page, since at the first load, both `h2Heigth` and `itemHeight` appear to be 0

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding this css class:

```scss
.scroll-content {
  max-height: calc(100% - 60px);
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;

  p {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
  }
}
```

and then in my page:

```js
<div className={'scroll-content'}>
  <p>{searchResult?.description}</p>
</div>
```

Explanation: `calc(100% - 60px)` is the entire content minus the height of everything outside the scroll content. (apparently, the footer does not count)

This works for the devices I'm targeting. However, this is a rather unsatisfying solution because it will break as soon as I add content to the page unless I happen to remember to update the difference value